# ajax firing for every button when a single button is clicked

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm adding a button to every list_item on page.
The buttons are generated, with their correct id.
And the button value changes as it should - as shown in the alert.

But on a single button click, the alert fires as many times as there are buttons on the page. 
The alert always shows the same (and correct) button id. 
Without the alert, this causes the button value to switch back and forth if other buttons are clicked in the meantime.

Generate the buttons:

```
function create_saved_message_button( ) { 
    $button_label = "Save";
?>
    <td width="15%" class="thread-options">
        <input type="button" class="savedbutton" value = "<?php echo $button_label ?>"  id = "<?php echo message_thread_id(); ?>" />
    </td>   
<?php
}
```

The ajax:

```
function saved_message_button_javascript() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.savedbutton').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
            var button = $(this);  
            var butt_txt = $(button).attr('value');

            alert($(button).attr("id"));

            $(button).attr({'disabled': true});
            var data = {
                action: 'saved_button_clicked',
            };

            $.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if(butt_txt == 'Save') {
                    $(button).attr('value', 'Un-Save');
                }
                else {
                    $(button).attr('value', 'Save');
                }
            });
            $(button).attr({'disabled': false});
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Is there any way to stop the multiple alerts? 
I think that would solve the value switching problem.

Then I just need to pass the button id to the php function saved_button_clicked

The add_actions:

```
    add_action( 'messages_inbox_list_item', 'create_saved_message_button', 1 ); 
//this was the problem
    //add_action('messages_inbox_list_item', 'saved_message_button_javascript');
//the solution - use this instead
add_action('after_member_messages_threads', 'saved_message_button_javascript');
    add_action('wp_ajax_saved_button_clicked', 'process_save_button_clicked');
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the middle add_action call and include the javascript event handler directly in your php or only call it once?

Comment: It needs a hook so that it isn't created too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood something. I created a html with 5 buttons and your javascript in it but I couldn't find the behavior you described. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SgTrf/).

Comment: dragon - thanks. 

I see in your example html source that the javascript only appears once. 

For mine, it appears for every button created. 
Due, I think, to this being a Wordpress page. 
And I'm using add_actions: (see editied post above)


So maybe the issue is how to generate the javascript only once... ?

Comment: @sam3d: that's definitely where the problem is. You have added event handler multiple times.

Comment: Yup - found a hook after all the list_items are created and (dumb) problem solved.  Thanks for creating the fiddle.